# How to overlap the white pixels from binary onto original image?

Tags: python, image-processing, overlay

I have an aerial image:

[image]

I was able to get a binary image of the riverbed of the river part:

[image: Riverbed binary Image]

After applying a distance transform and some segmentation techniques I was able to get a binary image of the mean riverline:

[image: Riverline binary Image]

My question is: how to overlay the white pixels from the riverline so that they're on "top" of the original image?

Here´s an example:

[image: Result example]

Comment: Simply add the 2 images?

Comment: it doesnt work, i wanted them to be shown as plot and when i add them together the riverline is not shown

Comment: Only the original image

Comment: How did you make your “result example”? It seems to me that you know that this can done? Also, it is strange to ask a yes/no question here. Are you sure you’re not intending to ask how to do this, rather than if it can be done?

Comment: its an exercise, from a image processing course, that i dont have the answer for and the image is shown as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple way to solve your problem. But it works.

```
import cv2

original = cv2.imread('original.png')  # Orignal image
mask = cv2.imread('line.png')          # binary mask image
result = original.copy()

for i in range(original.shape[0]):
    for j in range(original.shape[1]):
        result[i, j] = [255, 255, 255] if mask[i, j][0] == 255 else result[i, j]


cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)   # saves modified image to result.png
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: However its giving me an error: "invalid index to scalar variable"

Comment: in this line:  result[i, j] = [255, 255, 255] if mask[i, j][0] == 255 else result[i, j]

Comment: Did you use exact my code? It should not give any error.

Comment: what is your python version ?

Comment: Yes i did. It's 3.8

Comment: I was reading the image using Imageio module. Using cv2 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your images are numpy arrays called `img` and `mask`. Let's also assume that `img` has shape `(M, N, 3)`, while `mask` has shape `(M, N)`. Finally, let's assume that `img` is off dtype `np.uint8` while `mask` is of type `np.bool_`.  If the last assumption isn't true, start with

```
mask = mask.astype(bool)
```

Now you can set your river channel to 255 directly:

```
img[mask, :] = 255
```

If `img` were a single grayscale image without a third dimension, as in your last example, you would just remove the `:` from the index expression above. In fact, you could write it to work for any number of dimensions with

```
img[mask, ...] = 255
```